# System.Security.Cryptography vs PCLCrypto

Tags: c#, encryption, portable-class-library, pcl-crypto

We are in the process of gutting a lot of shared functionality in our system and porting it to PCL libraries. I am having an issue using PCLCrypto. I am taking some existing data in our database, and trying to decrypt it with the same algorithm. I get the value back, but there are 16 extra bytes at the end that are just garbage.

See Code below:
**Old Algorithm using System.Security.Cryptography**

```
public static string SymmetricEncrypt(this string plaintext, string key, SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm)
{
    byte[] keyBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(key.Hash(HashAlgorithm.MD5));
    byte[] plainTextBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext);

   var symmetricAlgorithm = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
    symmetricAlgorithm.Key = keyBuffer;
    symmetricAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

    var encryptor = symmetricAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor();
    byte[] cipherBuffer = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(plainTextBuffer, 0, plainTextBuffer.Length);
    symmetricAlgorithm.Clear();

    return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherBuffer);
}


 public static string SymmetricDecrypt(this string cipherText, string key, SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm)
    {
        byte[] keyBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(key.Hash(HashAlgorithm.MD5));
        byte[] cipherTextBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        var symmetricAlgorithm = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        symmetricAlgorithm.Key = keyBuffer;
        symmetricAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

        var decryptor = symmetricAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] plainTextBuffer = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(cipherTextBuffer, 0, cipherTextBuffer.Length);
        symmetricAlgorithm.Clear();

        return Encoding.Default.GetString(plainTextBuffer);
    }
```

**Decryption using PCLCrypto**

```
public static string SymmetricDecrypt(this string cipherText, string key, SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm) {
    byte[] keyBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(key.Hash(HashAlgorithm.MD5));
    byte[] cipherTextBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

    ISymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider symmetricAlgorithm = WinRTCrypto.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(PCLCrypto.SymmetricAlgorithm.AesEcb);

    var symmetricKey = symmetricAlgorithm.CreateSymmetricKey(keyBuffer);
    var decryptor = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicEngine.CreateDecryptor(symmetricKey);
   byte[] plainTextBuffer = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(cipherTextBuffer, 0, cipherTextBuffer.Length);
    return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBuffer, 0, plainTextBuffer.Length);
}
```

Using the old version: plainTextBuffer is 16 bytes, new version it is 32 bytes.

Help!

Comment: It is an active GitHub project so you should report an issue there to reach its authors.

Comment: On the very bottom line of your posted code, I assume you meant to type plainTextBuffer, not plainText.  The difficulty here is that the GitHub project is just accessing other APIs and does not implement its own AES.  But having said that, I cannot find any reason for this behavior in the repository nor in your code.  Strange, you declare plainTextBuffer in a call to TransformFinalBlock, a function I thought never returned larger than the actual block size of the algorithm, yet you do have those extra bytes.  I am sorry to say I am stumped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a padding issue.

Looking at the source for the base class SymmetricAlgorithm in .NET, which is the base of the AesCryptoServiceProvider, the default padding is PaddingMode.PKCS7.  You don't appear to have defined a padding mode, so I would assume the default still applies.

Whilst I haven't used the PCLCrypto library before, having a quick look at github there are a couple of AesEcb algorithms: AesEcb and AesEcbPkcs7.  The absence of a padding mode from the name of AesEcb would imply to me that it has no padding (and thus hasn't removed any padding), which would be the equivalent of PaddingMode.None in the .NET libraries.

Try using the PCLCrypto.SymmetricAlgorithm.AesEcbPkcs7 algorithm in PCLCrypto and see if this removes the padding that you are seeing at the end of the output.

***Update***

I've just tested this, and it appears to work correctly and remove the padding you would be seeing:

```
public static string SymmetricDecrypt(this string cipherText, string key, SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm) {
    byte[] keyBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(key.Hash(HashAlgorithm.MD5));
    byte[] cipherTextBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

    ISymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider symmetricAlgorithm = WinRTCrypto.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(PCLCrypto.SymmetricAlgorithm.AesEcbPkcs7);

    var symmetricKey = symmetricAlgorithm.CreateSymmetricKey(keyBuffer);
    var decryptor = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicEngine.CreateDecryptor(symmetricKey);
   byte[] plainTextBuffer = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(cipherTextBuffer, 0, cipherTextBuffer.Length);
    return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBuffer, 0, plainTextBuffer.Length);
}
```

The only change was changing the algorithm from PCLCrypto.SymmetricAlgorithm.AesEcb to PCLCrypto.SymmetricAlgorithm.AesEcbPkcs7

Comment: You are my hero. Thank you so much.