# C# Hashing Base64 encoded string length

Tags: c#, hash, base64

I am hashing the binary contents of a file and sending the hash along with the contents of that file to a 3rd party web service. They will validate that the hash matches the file.

I am using WinRTCrypto.HashAlgorithmProvider and the SHA-256 algorithm

```
var cryptoProvider = WinRTCrypto.HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithm.Sha256);
var hash_VA = this.cryptoProvider.HashData(this.DocumentBytes);
```

`hash_VA` results in a byte array of 32 bytes. If I convert that to base 64

```
var hashBase64_VA = Convert.ToBase64String(hash_VA);
```

I get a string that is **44** chars in length. The trouble is the 3rd web service is getting a base 64 hash of **88** characters.

If I convert the the bytes to HEX I get **64** characters

```
BitConverter.ToString(this.cryptoProvider.HashData(bytesFromHex)).Replace("-", String.Empty)
```

64 however is not 88, however if i take that HEX string e.g.

```
DBA70AB40B20A4F09C15A5908D31360F39CFBF20A0458F49641B0D9670689985
```

and drop it in https://www.base64encode.org/ that does encode it to 88 chars.

How do I generate that 88 character base 64 string in C#? I am clearly missing some fundamental knowledge here

Comment: There is no reason nor does it make sense to hexadecimal encode a Base64 encoding unless there is a problem with the non-alphanumeric characters "=", "/" and "=". There are alternative Base64 encodings that use other characters non-alphanumeric characters.

Comment: You should ask the third-party web service provider how they calculate the hash.

Comment: I have and I have their source from that validation. I seem to be doing the reverse but clearly not

Comment: Are you sure they aren't using SHA-512?

Comment: Yes, definetly SHA 256.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the hash to hex and then base64 encode that:

```
using PCLCrypto;
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace SOcrypto
{
    class Program
    {
        static string Hex(byte[] bb)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < bb.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(bb[i].ToString("X2"));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Hello, World!");
            var cryptoProvider = WinRTCrypto.HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithm.Sha256);
            var hash_VA = cryptoProvider.HashData(testData);

            Console.WriteLine("hash_VA.Length = " + hash_VA.Length);

            var asHex = Hex(hash_VA);
            var asB64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(asHex));

            Console.WriteLine("asB64.Length = " + asB64.Length);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> hash_VA.Length = 32
> asB64.Length = 88

#### Note for .NET 5 and later

You can use `var asHex = Convert.ToHexString(testData)` instead of the `Hex` function.

[Documentation for `Convert.ToHexString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tohexstring).

Comment: @Downvoter Please explain what's wrong with that. It does what the OP did manually.

Comment: Not sure about the downvote (I haven't tested this), but there might be some padding issues generated by the Algorithm mode. See if this can give some clues on the matter: [System.Security.Cryptography vs PCLCrypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32104440/system-security-cryptography-vs-pclcrypto).

Comment: @Jimi The padding in that link applies to encryption/decryption, not the hash.

Comment: Yes, not exactly the reason why I proposed that link, but I can confirm that with your code, those are the results. A test using [ToBase64Transform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tobase64transform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) returns a string of 44 bytes (different from `Convert.ToBase64String()`). But, in this case the Hex transformation returns a string of 52 char and (just in case) a URLEncoded string of 120 bytes. So, the values returned by your code probably represent the correct result.

Comment: @PatLong-MunkiiYebee I noticed you just accepted this answer—I've added a note about not needing the `Hex` function if you're using .NET 6 or later.